# What value does next have for each node in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to write a push method for a linked list stack. The stack should use a specific class for the nodes. This specific class has two input variables for the constructor one of which is the value that I need to push and the other one is a next reference to the next node:

```
public class StackNode<T> {
    protected T data;
    protected StackNode<T> next;
    
    public StackNode(T v, StackNode<T> n)
    {
        data = v;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

If I want to add my first node to the list at index 0, what value should "next" take if it points to the next node? Would it be 1?

```
StackNode<ElementType> linkedList=new StackNode<ElementType>(value,1);
```

Comment: The parameters of `(value,1)` would not compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a list of one node, then pass `null`

```
new StackNode<ElementType>(value, null);
```

Otherwise, you need to have another node with a value

```
new StackNode<ElementType>(value, new StackNode<ElementType>(new ElementType<Integer>(1), null));
```

I would suggest creating a terminal node like `new StackNode<>(null, null)`, then implementing an `equals` method on that class

Answer (score 0):

`next` should point to the existing contents of the list:

```
StackNode<ElementType> linkedList = new StackNode<>(value, existingList);
```

where existingList is a variable of type `StackNode<ElementType>`

It might be defined as:

```
StackNode<ElementType> existingList = null; // empty list without nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the actual stack is implemented. If its a "true" linked list, each node should hold the next node and should be of the same `StackNode` type. The issue is then what is the value of that initial first node? It would make a the most sense to store that as a `null` value, since the only other option is to have some special `EndStackNode` class which would just be some almost useless boilerplate. Just make sure that you are careful around that null, and are putting the proper null checks whenever you are iterating over the stack.

To get around this you might want to look into [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which is super useful for just that sort of thing.

```java
import java.util.Optional;

public class StackNode<T> {
    protected T data;
    protected Optional<StackNode<T>> next;
    
    public StackNode(Y v) {
        this(v, Optional.empty());
    }

    public StackNode(T v, Optional<StackNode<T> n>)
    {
        data = v;
        next = n;
    }
}
```